# Do i have to update the security stamp manually whenever a user request a password change or it is handled automatically by user manager?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

As Microsoft stated on their website : 
Security Stamp:

> A random value that must change whenever a users credentials change (password changed, login removed)

I am writing an action where the admin can change a users password manually:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword(string userId, string newPassword)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                TempData.Put("M", new ResultMessage
                {
                    CssClassName = "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible",
                    Title = "Failed!",
                    Message = "User not found!"
                });

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            string resetToken = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

            var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, resetToken, newPassword);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var ress = await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user); //Is this step necessary?

                if (ress.Succeeded)
                {
                    TempData.Put("M", new ResultMessage
                    {
                        CssClassName = "alert alert-success alert-dismissible",
                        Title = "Success!",
                        Message = "Password updated successfully!"
                    });

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                TempData.Put("M", new ResultMessage
                {
                    CssClassName = "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible",
                    Title = "Failed!",
                    Message = "Failed at the security stamp step!"
                });

                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }

            TempData.Put("M", new ResultMessage
            {
                CssClassName = "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible",
                Title = "Failed!",
                Message = "Failed to reset password!"
            });

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

and validating the security stamp every 15 minutes to force user logout on password change like this :

```
    services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>

            options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
            );
```

do i have to generate a new security stamp on every password change or is it done automatically by the user manager ?

using ASP.Net Core 2.2

Comment: You cam see in the code that [`ResetPasswordAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L920) calls [`UpdatePasswordHash`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L2398) that then calls `UpdateSecurityStampInternal` - so no, you don't have to do it. But relying on implementation details isn't ideal and it isn't doing any harm, so you could just leave it in.

Comment: Thank you if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Well, it's a bit short for an answer, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing. The [docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0#isecuritystampvalidator-and-signout-everywhere):

> Call `userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user)`to force existing cookies to be invalided the next time they are checked. Most of the Identity UI account and manage pages call `userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user)` after changing the password or adding a login

But in the "Default Identity UI" that is not called [after a password reset](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d0ca5a8d20ac50a33d5451e998a5d411a810c8d7/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V5/Account/ResetPassword.cshtml.cs#L120). That was confusing.

As @stuartd commented above, `UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync` calls [`UpdatePasswordHash`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d0ca5a8d20ac50a33d5451e998a5d411a810c8d7/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L937) which calls [UpdateSecurityStampInternal](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d0ca5a8d20ac50a33d5451e998a5d411a810c8d7/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L2474).

If one calls `userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync` manually after a password change, it calls [UpdateSecurityStampInternal](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d0ca5a8d20ac50a33d5451e998a5d411a810c8d7/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L896).

So it does the same thing, but I would not rely on an undocumented internal implementation.

That "Default Identity UI" is lacking in multiple areas. I think whomever wrote that bit of the UI also wrote the Identity mechanism, so was aware of the implementation detail. We should not make such assumptions.

So I'd just do it again to be sure.